# Subversion tree conflicts when attempting to merge near identical branch

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control, cornerstone

I have an iOS project under Subversion source control and I am using Cornerstone as my SVN client. (I have also tried using XCode for this as well)

I've had numerous problems merging branches, and hope someone can help!

In the simplest test I have done, I have:

1. Created a new branch from the trunk
2. Made one small text change in one file in the new branch
3. Immediately attempted to merge the change back into the trunk from the branch.

When Cornerstone analyses the merge contents, it reports lots of tree conflicts and newly added files.

Other (potentially) relevant info:

- I am the only person working on the project at present, so there are no other changes being made.
- I have tried merging from branch-branch, trunk-branch, branch-trunk all with the same result
- The server is using SVN v1.4.2, my client is v1.6.17. I am suspecting that this may be the cause, but am looking to get this confirmed if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is due to the server being v1.4.2.

I deleted my existing working copy and checked out a fresh copy, ensuring that the SVN version was set in the check-out dialog box to 1.4.

Now, when I attempt a merge, I only get the options to "Cherry Pick Changes" or "Advanced Merge". The "Synchronise a branch" or "Reintegrate a branch" options no longer appear, so these must be options not supported on 1.4.2 and be the cause of the conflict explosion I was seeing.

In summary, to merge between my branches it appears that I have to select the specific revisions that I wish to merge.

Comment: If I recall correctly, merge-tracking was implemented in Subversion 1.5,

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - yes, but it **must not** generate tree-conflicts